# Unable to divide a matrix and vector in keras

Tags: python, keras, array-broadcasting

The matrix `a` has shape `(4,3)` and `z` has shape `(4,)`.
My intent is I want to divide every 3 dim vector in `a` with scalar in `z`.
Consider the below example:

Input:

```
a = [[1,1,1],
 [2,2,2],
 [2,2,2],
 [5,5,5]]

z = [10,10,10,5]
```

Expected Output:

```
[[.1,.1,.1],
 [.2,.2,.2],
 [.2,.2,.2],
 [1,1,1]]
```

Below is my attempt to do the same using keras `Lambda` layer where `K.sum(xin[0], axis=1)` would be `a` and `xin[1]` would be `z`

```
 x = Lambda(lambda xin: K.sum(xin[0], axis=1) / xin[1], name='mean')([x1,x2])
```

But when I run this code, I am getting the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [4,3] vs. [4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = Lambda(
    lambda xin: K.sum(xin[0], axis=1) / K.expand_dims(xin[1]), name='mean'
)([x1,x2])
```

The function `expand_dims` will turn `(4,)` into `(4,1)`, making both shapes compatible.